# Adding class to content 'Read More'

Tags: joomla-3.4, template-override, com-content

I want to add a class to the Read More link found in //components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php

I want the class to be:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary readmore-link">
```

But I can't find where to edit it.  The standard html output in the frontend is:

```
<p class="readmore">
    <a class="btn readmore-link" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=23:re-leve&amp;catid=17&amp;Itemid=330" title="TEST">Read more ...</a>
</p>
```

I know I need to edit the file with an override (putting it here):

//templates/TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

but the only code it refers to within the file is:

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.readmore', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'link' => $link)); ?>
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JLayoutHelper` renders layouts originally  from `/layouts` folder.

First parameter is basically path to file. Just replace `.` with `/` in your mind :).

So `readmore.php` is located at

`/layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php`

Copy it to

`templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php`

and edit it there.